# Find certain text and get complete text

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I'm using a proxy to scrape data of this url: [CNN Article](http://edition.cnn.com/2012/12/22/world/africa/egypt-election/index.html?hpt=hp_t1)

I would like to get the entire article text (heading not necessarily). So I tried this:

```
$(data).find("div:contains('Across the river from Cairo')");
```

This wil find the piece of text but when I do my thing with it `myThing = $(this).text();` It seems it is getting a lot more than just the article. This might have something to do with the way the HTML is constructed. If I look at the source I see the article text is confined in `p` However changing the `div:contains` in to `p:contains` only gets me the first few lines (obviously)

So my question is how do I get the article text regardless it's HTML construction. I'm looking for something(code) that will say:

```
find.('Across the river from Cairo') and get this text and all the text underneath this text();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the desired results from that article with the selector `p.cnn_storypgraphtxt`. To get the whole article, you can use `$("p.cnn_storypgraphtxt").text()` or

```
$("p.cnn_storypgraphtxt").map(function(){return $(this).text;}).get().join("\n");
```

---

For getting the text that follows a certain expression, you might use `.last()` to get the last selected node (i.e. the lowermost in the DOM) and then `.nextAll()` like

```
$(":contains('Across the river from Cairo')").last().nextAll().text()
```

but that will contain a lot of unwanted stuff.

Comment: Im actually looking for a code that will say: Find this text and get all the text starting from this point on. It could be any website so your code wouldn't work

Comment: So the starting point of the text I need should be the text string `Across the river from Cairo`

Comment: I think I need 'slice' or something

Comment: But "all the text" in a website is likely more than you want. If you can't restrict it to some selectable elements, it would contain ads, footers etc. You then would need to do NLP to cut those out, or use visual text recognition (OCR) like Google does.

Comment: No, not necessarily. If the starting point of the text is ('Across the river from Cairo') all the way down, than I can get just the first 100 or so characters. I forgot to mention that I dont need all the text...my bad

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$someString = $(data).find("div:contains('Across the river from Cairo')").html();
```

use that string for manipulations or whatever.

Comment: The problem is that this will get me a lot of text/images etc. which I don't need. Which is oke since there is no way around this but it would really help if this html is only under the text to find. It will make it easy to constrain to a certain amount of text.

Comment: You can use :filter to filter the image tags. As you have used text(), it 'll get the text which is under only the specified DOM element.

Comment: No, it is getting me ALL the text in the div (so Print Email More sharing...By Ben Brumfield and Amir Ahmed, CNN December 22, 2012 -- Updated 1045 GMT (1845 HKT)...) It is not getting me only the text underneath

Comment: Filter the links, images. Doing so will remove most of whatever you wish to exclude

Comment: It would really help if you could tell me how to remove evrything before the given text or show only the text underneath. Using filter in the way you are suggesting would only work in this specific example. However the link I provided in my question is just for example purpose. In reality it can be any link. Filtering wouldnt work because I don't know what Im getting in data to begin with

Comment: To get only that why can't you go for their feeds and get the access of each using jSon and jQuery

Comment: Because it could be any website not just CNN...If you could of some code that will show the text in this direction ______> Please do tell me